# Display a sprited background image DIV next to an H3

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I have the following HTML:

```
<div style="display: inline-block; width: auto;">
    <h3>
        Search Criteria
    </h3>
    <div style="background-image: url(jQuery-UI/images/ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: -16px -144px; width: 16px;
        height: 16px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the `div` to display to the right of the `h3`. However, what's happening is the `div` is displaying directly under the `h3`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to `float` your `H3` and `div`

have a look at this jsFiddle. I added a background colour to the div as I don't have the image

http://jsfiddle.net/CPvXA/

Comment: You're welcome :) You might want to put a <div style="clear:both;"></div> directly after the div with a background image. just to clear the floating so as to not interfere with any content afterwards

Comment: You shouldn't need to float both elements. If you do, don't forget to clearfix the container.